# Using DirectorySearcher to query multiple OUs

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have the following code:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(distributionListsListADSPath);
var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry) 
          { SizeLimit = int.MaxValue, PageSize = int.MaxValue };
var result = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```

The problem is I want to search two seperate OUs.

So what I do is run through this twice, once where

```
private const string distributionListsListADSPath = 
"LDAP://OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Groups,DC=enron,DC=com";
```

and a second where it is

```
private const string distributionListsListADSPath = 
"LDAP://OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=enron,DC=com";
```

Ideally, I could do something like

```
private const string distributionListsListADSPath = 
"LDAP://OU=Distribution Lists | OU = Security Groups ,OU=Groups,DC=enron,DC=com";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the hierarchy of your container, it is hard to form a proper answer.

You may need to use Extensible Match which is described here: http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch

Good Luck -jim

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"(|(OU=Distribution Lists)(OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=enron,DC=com))"
```

Comment: will this filter give any performance issue?  `(| (OU=0001,OU=Groups,DC=abc,DC=com)(OU=0002,OU=Groups,DC=abc,DC=com) ....(OU=0999,OU=Groups,DC=abc,DC=com)) `