# Finding user from 2 OU at Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory

I have a .Net application that reads user from active directory that is in a specific OU (ABCUsers). The following is the code:

```
        string DomainIP = "some domain IP";
        string ContainerConnectionString = "OU=ABCUsers,DC=test,DC=com";
        PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainIP, ContainerConnectionString, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);

        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        UserPrincipal findUser = new UserPrincipal(domain);
        findUser.SamAccountName = "some username";
        searcher.QueryFilter = findUser;
        UserPrincipal foundUser = (UserPrincipal)searcher.FindOne();
```

The above code works fine, but I need to change the code so that it retrieves a user whether he/she is in OU=ABCUsers or OU=XYZUsers.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have two containers and you want to find a user who might be in either, then you have no choice really but to search in the context that is common to both containers, IE the container within which both of yours reside.  In your case, it's the root of the domain:

```
"DC=test,DC=com";
```

Comment: It is one container, not 2. the domain name is "test.com" so "test" is the container and "com" is the sub. I'm not expert in AD so please excuse me if I'm using the wrong terms

Comment: An OU is a container; you are dealing with three containers here in your example: the domain root, the `ABCUsers`, and the `XYZUsers`.

Comment: I feel I'm a bit confused. The code above works when searching for users in the "test.com" domain and inside the "ABCUsers" OU. I need the same thing, just instead of searching only inside ABCUsers, I need it also to search in XYZUsers. Is there any other information I can provide to reveal the consufsion?

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is just change `"OU=ABCUsers,DC=test,DC=com"` to `"DC=test,DC=com"`.

Comment: "DC=test,DC=com" will search for all OU's in the domain, so if I have a third OU named "123Users" it will also search in it. also this will required that the user being used to run the program to have permission on the entire domain, but we are only given permission on ABCUsers and XYZUsers

Comment: Well then search the first one then search the next one in succession.

Comment: Isn't there a way to search only one time? I have many methods that use almost the same code. This suggestion will require changing all of these methods

Comment: Maybe if you update your question with a little bit more detail about what you're doing, it will be easier to help you.  You are withholding too much information so we can only really give you a general answer.

Comment: I'm not withholding anything. I actually took the exact code. I only changed the values. Actually, someone else had already asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540595/using-directorysearcher-to-query-multiple-ous It is just the suggested link didn't work for me

Comment: Is there anything I can add? I really hope if you can help. Thanks